# Monacaから外部サーバのDBは利用できますか？

Tags: javascript, monaca, mysql, ajax

ただいま、Monacaでのアプリ開発を行っております。

Monaca側からレンタルサーバのDBを利用したいと考えているのですが、
それが可能であるかどうかが分かりません。

一応調べてはみたのですが、それが可能かどうかがハッキリと分からなかったので
ここで質問させて頂きました。

もし出来る場合は、その方法を教えて頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

monacaアプリからajaxでPHPなどのcgi経由ならば、外部DBを利用できます。

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。試にやってみます。